# line-height not working with ::before pseudo-element

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

It seems every property I tested with ::before works except line-height. It's consistent across browsers. I don't see this in the spec. Am I doing something wrong? If not, is there a clean workaround for this? I would like a different line-height for the body of the div and the ::before. EDIT: After further research, it seems it works if the line-height is larger than the DIV line-height, but not smaller. This definitely seems like a bug. I added a fourth DIV to demonstrate this.

HTML:

```html
<div id="content1">content<br />content<br />content<br /></div>
<div id="content2">content<br />content<br />content<br /></div>
<div id="content3">content<br />content<br />content<br /></div>
<div id="content4">content<br />content<br />content<br /></div>
```

CSS:

```css
div {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 150px;
    line-height: 20px;
    width: 110px;    
}

div::before {
    color: red;
    content: "before \a before \a before \a";
    font-family: courier new;
    font-size: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    white-space: pre;
}

#content1::before {
    line-height: 10px;
}

#content2::before {
    line-height: 8px;
}

#content3::before {
    line-height: 6px;
}

#content4::before {
    line-height: 30px;   
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/weGGn/

Comment: Works fine for me in FF and Chrome...

Comment: I updated the jsfiddle with three divs. Are you seeing different line-height for the red text? I see no difference in any browser.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to define `line-height` on the `div`, because `div:before`  takes `div` `line-height`, not `:before div`. So, write like this:

```css
div:before {
    color: red;
    content: "before \a before \a before \a";
    font-family: courier new;
    font-size: 10px;
    letter-spacing: 10px;
    white-space: pre;
}

div {
    line-height: 10px;
}
```

Check this: [http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/weGGn/3/'](http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/weGGn/3/%27)

Answer (score 4):

Some additions to @sandeep answer:

Line-height property is apparently working the same in most of the new browsers. You might face a problem with [Windows Phone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Phone) browser (i.e. using [Nokia Lumia 920](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nokia_Lumia_920)) which picks the element's line-height property and applies it to both the element and its pseudo (:before, :after).

So the bottom line is, you assign the line-height's value in the element itself and use line-height: inherit for the pseudo that works as a cross-browser thing. You may need to try it also and see if it works for you.

Comment: This. `line-height: inherit;` on the `::before` element did the trick.